# Is there a way to dynamically specify a config spec depending on the programming that is run?

Tags: sas, config, clearcase

I am running SAS jobs through clearcase. However, depending on the project I am working on, I sometimes need to point to different labelled versions (or datetime stamps) of the source data/programs.

I find this to be quite a risk, as moving between projects it is easy to forget to change the config specs. As each project program has specific version requirements, is there a way I can dynamically define the clearcase config specs using sas `x` commands for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the x command is enabled, then you can set a config spec from within a view with [`cleartool setcs`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-64)

You actually can use a config spec stored in a file and pass the file as parameter to `cleartool setcs`. You could consider using the right file depending on the environment in which your job operates.

Be aware though that:

- the command can be done directly from within the view or using the `-tag viewtag` parameter.
- if done for a snapshot view, it will trigger an update, so it might be more suited (because quicker to switch config spec) in a dynamic view.